# How to set focus follows mouse in 22.10?

Tags: focus

I've just noticed that it seems to be not working. It used to be a gnome-tweaks thing. What is the correct way to do this now?

I see some comment about "sloppy" but not where it is found.

Comment: "Focus on hover" in Gnome Tweaks, Windows tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still in Tweaks, under the Windows section.

[image: GNOME Tweaks]